# to change xml data to ArrayCollection

Tags: xml, apache-flex, flex3, arraycollection

I have xml file with data as below and i want to convert this into Flex ArrayCollection including the id and name of the tags. I am using httpService to get the file.

data.xml

```
<data>
    <result month="Jan" value="0.666">
        <info id="jan01Display" name="jhon" age="20" />
  <info id="jan02Display" name="adams" age="24" />
  <info id="jan03Display" name="prasad" age="27" />
    </result>
</data>
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not return an array collection instead of XML then. Just change the HTTPService and remove the `resultFormat="e4x"` attribute and then change your result handler to include something like:

```
var myAC:ArrayCollection = event.result.data.result;
```

instead of:

```
var myXML:XML = event.result.data;
```

I think that should do it for you. If not, post a code example of both your HTTPService and your Result Handler and We'll figure it out for you.